# Javascript String Property

Tags: javascript

I came across some strange (legacy?) JS syntax this morning which boiled down to: 
`var example = "String".Property = "Value";`

Before altering this code, I couldn't find a valid case for this implementation that I am aware of...

```js
var example = "String".Property = "Value";
console.log(example);

"String".Property = "Value";
console.log("String".Property);
console.log(String.Property);
```

What actually happens to `"String".Property` in the first part of the above snippet, does it just get discarded immediately after being assigned ?

Comment: `"String"` is a literal string, and since you don't keep a reference to it it will be garbage collected whether you assign a property to it or not.

Comment: I don't know where you found this code, but it's bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals are `string` primitive values. When followed by a dot (`.`) operator, they are implicitly converted to a String instance.

The statement

```
var example = "String".Property = "Value";
```

is equivalent to

```
var example = "Value";
```

There is no point to the `.Property` reference.

Subsequently,

```
"String".Property = "Value";
```

has no net effect on the global environment, because the string constant `"String"` is converted to a String instance and the property is set, but then the object is discarded because it isn't assigned to anything.

Every use of the string constant `"String"` that results in an implicit object creation will cause a new unique object to be created.

Comment: Indeed, `typeof "foo" !== typeof new String("foo")`

Comment: Multi-part answers should be closed as "Too Broad" and not answered.

Comment: Seeing obscure code like this always makes me question why it was implemented in the first place / what don't I know. Thanks for the clarity.